# Community conscious on viewing hot questions from artificial intelligence and cross validated stack exchange

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, ai-stack-exchange, cross-validated

It is a well-known fact that overlap is high between the three sites: [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

If we go through the meta-questions of individual sites, we can also find a lot of differences based on what is on-topic on a particular site.

No one can deny that they are highly related or overlapped to each other. So, it is clear that the users, either beginners or intermediates, or experts, can contribute to the three sites based on the questions asked. But, it can be noticed that the users contributing to all three or at least two sites are rare.

The reasons I'm thinking are that the users are either interested in contributing to a single site or may be unaware of the questions on other sites.

The latter reason can be at least slightly fixed by streaming the hot questions on the other two sites somewhere on the main page of the third site.

It will provide users an advantage to read at least two to five hot questions on the other two sites so that they can diversify the contribution.

Do the members of the Data Science SE welcome this feature?

---

Since I am sure that Artificial Intelligence community is ready to ask this feature, I asked [the same question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/community-conscious-on-viewing-hot-questions-from-artificial-intelligence-and-da) only on Cross Validated meta .

Comment: *My impression* as an infrequent SE-user is that relationships between the 3 sites are competitive to partly even hostile. For example, members from one community frequently question the need to have the other two and, in another case, there have been actions which could be interpreted as attempts reroute questions from one site to another. Given that, I *assume* that there is limited interest to facilitate any kind of collaboration. Personally, I have mostly focused on this site and currently I am not interested to participate in the other two at all.